# Sort the entity obtained from the Query class with values from the Statistics module

Tags: database, nodes

I am using the following code to sort the published nodes basing on the value stored from the Statistics module.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
      ->condition('status', 1)
      ->range(0, 5)
      ->sort('totalcount', 'DESC' );

$result = $query->execute();
```

The code is causing the following exception.

> Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryException: 'totalcount' not found in Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Tables->ensureEntityTable() (line 316 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Query/Sql/Tables.php).

How do I sort nodes basing on the *totalcount* value stored from the Statistics module?

Answer (score 3):

The code you are showing doesn't work because *totalcount* is not a Node property the node entity. That is a value saved in a different database table, not used from the Node entity. See [`statistics_get()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21statistics%21statistics.module/function/statistics_get/8.2.x), which retrieves the value you are looking for.

```php
if ($nid > 0) {
  // Retrieve an array with both totalcount and daycount.
  return db_query('SELECT totalcount, daycount, timestamp FROM {node_counter} WHERE nid = :nid', array(':nid' => $nid), array('target' => 'replica'))->fetchAssoc();
}
```

Since the entity query doesn't allow to join tables, you need to:

- Add a tag to the entity query you are using
- Implement [`hook_query_TAG_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/8.2.x) to alter the queries with the tag you added (Replace *TAG* with the tag you added to the entity query)

[`node_query_node_access_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_query_node_access_alter/8.2.x) is the implementation of that hook done from the Node module to allow an entity query to return just the nodes the currently logged-in user has access. You can use its code as guide to write your own implementation.

For example, I would start trying with the following code.

##### The code for the query

```php
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->addTag('statistics_totalcount')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->range(0, 5)
  ->sort('totalcount', 'DESC');

$result = $query->execute();
```

##### The hook implementation

```php
function mymodule_query_stastics_totalcount_alter(Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface $query) {
  $query->join('node_counter', 'nc', '%alias.nid = n.nid');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else, for me, I had to move the sort clause into the hook_query_TAG_alter() function because of a validation issue on the entity query object.

```
$query->leftJoin('node_counter', 'nc', '%alias.nid = node_field_data.nid');
$query->orderBy('totalcount', 'DESC');
```